# Is there any way to display the all the device which are connected to the same gateway..?

Tags: wireless-networking, arp

When I was tried arp -a on windows 10 it is not showing all the devices, even after ping to gateway IP address.

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make sense. ARP has almost nothing to do with gateway but the opposite. Also you can have have different gateways for different destinations. Every host in a LAN can be a gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The results you mention make sense to me.

When you run "arp -a", your system will show IP addresses and MAC addresses that it noticed within the cache timeout period, on a subnet that your computer is a part of.  However, if another laptop communicates with your Wi-Fi gateway and that traffic goes to the Internet or to a local printer, your computer is not part of that conversation.  So your computer will ignore such communication, and not notice it, and not enter such information into the ARP table.

(I suspect this might operate differently with Ethernet connections if you use a hub.  However, hubs are older devices that most people don't use, primarily because they operate at slower speeds since they are now older devices.  Instead, people tend to use switches these days, and a switch doesn't typically broadcast traffic.  So, if a switch is used, your desktop wouldn't unnecessarily receive the traffic, and so your desktop wouldn't notice the ARP traffic.  By the way, a router acts like a switch, and a firewall, "cable modem", and "DSL modem" all act like a router.)

Maybe you should explain why this doesn't make sense to you, or what you are trying to accomplish.  Maybe what you are trying to accomplish can be done by looking at the ARP table of the gateway device.  How to do that will depend on the gateway device.  If it runs some sort of Unix-like environment, running "arp -a" works there as well.  You may find that accessing that with HTTPS will provide a way to look at the ARP tables.

(If reading this has led you to a new understanding, but also caused a distinct new question, then consider accepting the best, most helpful answer to this question, and making a separate question on Superuser.  We tend to not like "evolving" questions, because that tends to lead to older useful answers becoming less relevant to the newer question.  However, if you feel that your original question is still relevant but just needs more clarification, then edit your original question.)

Comment: While -- as a relatively new SU member -- I really love the verbosity, I'm curious whether the norm would be to edit out the last section here as the question gains either more specificity or some other resolution, or does the same expectation not apply to answers?

Comment: @Arctiic : The norm is that some questions may have multiple answers, and we can't realistically expect every answer to keep evolving with the question.  It gets unpleasant when some answers don't match the current version of the question, and authors of answers are demotivated to keep investing effort if it seems like the question will never accept an answer until the question evolves first.  It is better to try to write a new question (after all, questions are free to create) that can then be answered separately, pursuing an ideal of all questions having a great (applicable) answer.

Comment: Including such Superuser.com-behaving tutorials in an answer is a bit unusual, but from my experience I could just smell ahead-of-time this question potentially turning into one of those frustrating "evolving questions", so I decided to try to nip that possibility in the bud before the problem surfaced.  (I admit that was a rather questionable/controversial decision I made, because it could easily be judged as point-pursuing that is off-topic to the original question.  I just played a hunch and wouldn't be very included to heavily defend myself from such an accusation in this case.)